# Windows PostMessage Issue C#

Tags: c#, sendkeys, postmessage

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam); 

public void keyPress(){
        const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        PostMessage(Process, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.Q, (IntPtr)Convert.ToInt32("00100001", 16));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        PostMessage(Process, WM_KEYUP, (int)Keys.Q, (IntPtr)Convert.ToInt32("C0100001", 16));
}
```

I am trying to call PostMessage with Keydown and keyup. I know the process is getting the message because I am watching the messages with spy++, and I sending the same wParam and lParams that are caused when I hit the button on the window myself. I've tried using SendKeys.sendwait along with setforeground but the same issue happens where the same message appears in spy++ but there is no active response in the window.

Comment: Is `Process` a window handle?

Comment: Oh sorry, Process is a IntPtr grabbed from Processes.MainWindowHandle.

Answer (score 0):

`SendInput` is a better alternative to simulate inputs correctly.

`PostMessage` may not always work because an application can check what window message is received and handle the input accordingly. E.g. whenever WM_KEYDOWN is received, popup a message box instead of doing anything with the input keys.